# Simple MySQL event #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql, sql, events

I'm trying to delete every expired posts that are expired on my database but it doesn't work

```
CREATE EVENT deleteExpiredPosts
 ON SCHEDULE 
 EVERY MINUTE
DO
 DELETE FROM `echos` WHERE `expires_at` < NOW();
```

but on PHPmyadmin it displays the error, I can't figure where I'm wrong

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;
```

Comment: You forgot the `AT ....` part. The event has to start at a specific timestamp.

Comment: MySQL `CREATE EVENT` syntax reference here: [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-event.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-event.html) **`CREATE EVENT foo ON SCHEDULE AT NOW() EVERY MINUTE DO ...`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE`.

The error message you posted should have mentioned "`...the right syntax to use near 'DO...'`" which is your hint that the parser encountered `DO` earlier than it expected to, in this case, because you left out the number of minutes.

If you saw that message, it would have been better if you had included it.  If you didn't, then phpMyAdmin is broken, because that's the message MySQL Server would have returned, and should have been displayed.